# Embed only some letters of google webfonts

Tags: javascript, webfonts, google-webfonts

I am using the `Roboto` and `Roboto Sans` webfonts of google. Reading the [Google Developers Doc](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started) there is a way to [only embed certain letters](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started#Optimizing_Requests) of a whole webfont, using `?text=customletters`.

I have generated these two embed links:

```
<!-- whole roboto font -->
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!-- only custom letters of roboto slab using text?= -->
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,700?text=I%20am%20an%20example' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

**1)** This does not work for me in safari. Is there something wrong with my code?

**2)** Although, is there a way to combine these two lines, to avoid two requests to another server on each page load?

**3)** Last and least, does the `@import` and `link href` way of embedding make any difference in performance?

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/marianrick/rue7uhf9/1/)

Comment: Why do you only want to load some letters? I don't think that it's for perfomance reasons?

Comment: Yes it is! I want to implement it to avoid images for SEO reasons, but I only do need 10 letters of the whole font. Saving about 90% of the webfonts size.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **1)** This does not work for me in safari. Is there something wrong with my code?

The problem is your GET parameters. A questionmark (`?`) separates the URL and the GET parameters. Each individual GET parameter is separated with an ampersand (`&`), though.

You're using two question marks:

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,700?text=I%20am%20an%20example
                                ^                          ^
```

This is wrong as the second one separates the first GET parameter (`family`) from the second one (`text`), so use an ampersand instead:

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,700&text=I%20am%20an%20example
                                ^                          ^
```

> **2)** Although, is there a way to combine these two lines, to avoid two requests to another server on each page load?

Google fonts can be split with a `|` like so:

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata|Roboto
                                                   ^
```

**HOWEVER** as you want all the characters in one font and only a few in a second font, then it's not possible. [**StackOverflow: Optimizing Multiple Google Web Fonts**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12380067/247893).

> **3)** Last and least, does the @import and link href way of embedding make any difference in performance?

`@import` blocks parallel downloading.

See [**StackOverflow: CSS: @import vs. <link href="">**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693643/css-import-vs-link-href)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is a great and clear answer. I had troubles to find the stack threads you have posted, they are very helpful!

Comment: @MarianRick You're very welcome. The first one was found by Googling `google multiple fonts text` and the second by Googling `link href vs @import`.

Answer (score 0):

Download the font and use FontForge (https://fontforge.github.io/en-US/), in this thread is a tutorial [how to remove characters from a font file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12976424/how-to-remove-characters-from-a-font-file)

Comment: google is much nicer than you are. google lets me download the fonts... https://developers.google.com/fonts/faq

Comment: Got it - "*You can download the fonts to use them for your mockups, in your documents or **to host them on your own server.***". It will still not use the Google CDN, though.